# Is function declaration essential to C programming?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation, nasm

I used to believe that we should declare a function which is defined in another file before use it, but recently I changed my way of thinking due to an experience of programming. For three files, `C` and `ASM`:

***main.c***

```
extern test_str;
/*extern myprint*/   --> If I add the line, gcc will report an error: called object ‘myprint’ is not a function
void Print_String() {
    myprint("a simple test", test_str);
}
```

***kernel.asm***

```
extern Print_String

[section .text]
global _start
global test_str
test_str    dd  14
_start:
    call Print_String
    jmp $
```

***another.asm***

```
[section .text]
global myprint
myprint:
    mov edx, [esp + 8]
    mov ecx, [esp + 4]
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    ret
```

*compile*

```
nasm -f elf another.asm -o another.o
gcc -c -g main.c -o main.o
nasm -f elf kernel.asm -o kernel.o
ld -o final main.o kernel.o another.o
```

*result*

```
./final 
a simple test
```

In my view, if I want to use the function `myprint` in ***main.c***, I should declare it using `extern` beforehand, because `myprint`  is defined in another file, but the result is exactly opposite. Just as ***main.c*** shows above. If I add the line `extern myprint`, I will get an error. However, without that declaration, I will get the right result.  What's more, I didn't define function `myprint` in ***main.c***, why can I use that function? Shouldn't I declare it beforehand?

Comment: What about if you compile with `gcc -c -g -W -Wall -pedantic -o main.o main.c`? What does GCC thing about this, then?

Comment: Try using extern myprint() to tell the compiler it's a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call a function without a prototype the compiler makes some assumptions and guesses about the parameters of that function. So you should declare it, but declare it as a function:

```
void myprint(const char *, const char *); /* Or whatever. */
```

Comment: Thank you! But why didn't you add `extern` in the beginning of the declaration? Anyhow the function is defined in other file.

Comment: @MarkZar "extern" is implicit for functions.

Comment: The bugs due to the asumptions made by the compiler in such situations are usually _very_ nasty...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the function `myprint`, though its not defined function in ***main.c***, with no error. This is because the compiler, while creating the object file fills in a NULL value against the symbol `myprint` in the object file created.

This NULL value is replaced at all places in the binary with the actual address of the function only during the linking phase. The linker refers to the symbol table across all the object files and resolves the symbol (wherever referred) with the actual address.

Certainly you shall see warnings/errors with the `-Werror -Wall` options to `gcc`. Although, you can get more insight using `objdump` as follows:

```
objdump -D main.o | less
```

Hope that helps to clear your doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really very detail. But I there is still one point that I cannot understand. I have added `-Werror -Wall`options to `gcc`, and added the function declaration in ***main.c***: `void myprint(char[], int);`, no errors. But for the function is defined outside `main.c`, shouldn't I add the `extern` in the beginning of the declaration, such as `extern void myprint(char[], int);`?